# Run Kubectl command on AKS

Tags: azure-aks

I have deployed a container image onto AKS successfully.

Now I want to run a command and a json file on the AKS using the pipeline once the container image is deployed onto AKS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to install azure cli & kubectl on your system.

Install Azure Cli
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli

Install Kubectl
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/

As far kubectl is installed, verify its version

```
kubectl version --client --short
Client Version: v1.23.1
```

The version in your case might be different.

Now is the time to get AKS credentials (kubeconfig) file to interact with AKS cluster.

```
az login
```

provide the credentials for azure AD.

```
az account set --subscription {subscription_id}

az aks get-credentials --resource-group MyAKSResoucceGroup --name MyAksCluster
```

Verify if cluster is connected

```
 kubectl config current-context
  MyAksCluster
```

You can play around with AKS and run all commands you want to run. Here is the cheatsheet or kubectl.

Kubectl Cheat-Sheet
https://www.bluematador.com/learn/kubectl-cheatsheet

In order to run commands using Azure DevOps on you need to create service connection in Azure DevOps to authenticate Azure DevOps with AKS.

```
Project Settings --> Service Connections --> New Kubernetes Service Connection --> Azure Subscription
```

[image]

Now you can run the kubernetes commands on this AKS using built in kubernetes task or using bash|powershell commands inside your pipeline.

Hope that helps you.

e:g

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '12345'
    namespace: 'default'
    command: 'apply'
    useConfigurationFile: true
    configurationType: 'inline'
    inline: 'abcd'
    secretType: 'dockerRegistry'
    containerRegistryType: 'Azure Container Registry'
```

Comment: Thanks Attiq, but i want to run the command using the pipeline instead of running from my local machine.

Comment: Which tool are using for pipeline. eg Jenkins or Azure DevOps.

Comment: I am using Azure DevOps

Comment: @SumanthKannedari I have modified my answers to your need.